# How to make an POST REST API call in nodejs using request-promise?

Tags: node.js, api, request-promise

I want to make an API call using REST. Please find my below code.

```
var resp = {};
var pool = {maxSockets: 10}
var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    port:'yyyy',
    hostname: 'xx.xx.xx.xx',
    uri:'https://apiurl/fun',
    body: {
        "some":payload
    },
    json: true,
    pool:true

};

 rp(options)
 .then(function (data){

      console.log("data",data);
     }) 
  .catch(function (err){ 
        console.log("err ",err); 
  });
```

But here Im getting an error like "Connection Timed out", If I use hostname. If i didnt use the hostname Im getting an error like "self signed certificate in certificate chain". What could be the issue> What are the options which are mandatory to solve this? Can you please help me with this?

Comment: My first guess would be that DNS is not set up correctly on your server

Comment: @Evert I'm making request to another server. And they have whitelisted our Ips. Is there any other thing we need to enable or configure?

Comment: Actually I retract my comment. Given that you got a timeout is a stronger suggestion that you are being firewalled. Are you sure that the ip the 3rd party service has for you is correct?

Comment: @Evert I have verified. It is correct only..

Comment: How did you verify it?

Comment: @Evert I have verified the IP from the client. Is there any other way? Could you please tell?

Comment: You could use a service like 'what is my ip' from your server. Maybe the outgoing request is ipv6 instead of ipv4.